# Go Benchmark how does it work

Tags: go

I've got my Go benchmark working with my API calls but I'm not exactly sure what it means below:

```
$ go test intapi -bench=. -benchmem -cover -v -cpuprofile=cpu.out
=== RUN TestAuthenticate
--- PASS: TestAuthenticate (0.00 seconds)
PASS
BenchmarkAuthenticate      20000            105010 ns/op            3199 B/op         49 allocs/op
coverage: 0.0% of statements
ok      intapi  4.349s
```

How does it know how many calls it should make? I do have a loop with `b.N` as size of the loop but how does Golang know how many to run?

Also I now have cpu profile file. How can I use this to view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TFM:

> The benchmark function must run the target code b.N times. The benchmark package will vary b.N until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably.

Comment: Great! How do I use cpu.out file?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper perhaps this will be helpful? http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs